# Using Angularfire2 to update user profile

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I'm new to Angular and learning :)

When updating user profile it save the profile changes then I get an error on `signOut`, wondering if anyone has any clue what could trigger this, code below...

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateProfile' of null
    at SafeSubscriber._next (auth.service.ts:66)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:207)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:145)
    at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:80)
    at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:55)
    at angularfire2.js:49
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:388)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:3824)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:387)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:138)
```

The code I'm invoking to update...

```
updateUserProfile() {
  this.store.dispatch(new AuthActions.SetIsPending(true));

  this.store
    .pipe(select(fromRoot.getAuthenticatedUserInformation))
.pipe(take(1)) <-- added this
    .subscribe(user => {
      this.fireauth.authState
.pipe(take(1)) <-- added this
      .subscribe(profile => {
        profile
          .updateProfile({
            displayName: user.displayName,
            photoURL: user.photoURL
          })
          .then(() => {
            this.store.dispatch(new AuthActions.SetIsPending(false));
          })
          .catch(error => {
            this.store.dispatch(new AuthActions.SetIsPending(false));
            console.log(error.message);
          });
      });
    });
}
```

Comment: Did you try logging `profile` to the console to check if it indeed has `updateProfile` on it?

Comment: within Visual Code it autocompletes on updateProfile method and it does save/update changes

Comment: Typescript knows the type of the `profile` argument, but it doesn't mean it's not null.

Comment: even if i change profile for someting else eg. prof1 it gives me the same result

Comment: with console.log(profile) it shows updateProfile function within "__proto__: F"

Comment: sure subscriptions were pending all the time so I only needed to take(1) from both store.select... and authState to be able to update without fuss, got it done!